# C# employee Multiple event

Tags: c#, class, oop

I need some help on C# programming.I am writing a small C# programming of Employee and events.
Employee Participating in events.I have written the code on Employee participation in single event.

I need some help for Employee Participating  in multiple events.Example Employee `Parvez` participating in multiple events `Football` , `chess`, `cricket`.

I need some help for displaying the Employee participating on that particular event.

The Following is the code:

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Employee> empList = new List<Employee>();

        empList.Add(new Employee() { ID = 101, Name = "Parvez Ali", EventID = 1 });
        empList.Add(new Employee() { ID = 102, Name = "Ashik Ali", EventID = 1 });
        empList.Add(new Employee() { ID = 103, Name = "aftab Ali", EventID = 2 });
        empList.Add(new Employee() { ID = 104, Name = "Muhammad Ali", EventID = 3 });

        string Choice2 = null;
        do
        {
            Console.Clear();
            MenuDisplay.DisplayEvents();
            Console.WriteLine("\nPlease Enter your choice");
            int Choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Output(Choice, empList);

            Console.WriteLine("\nDo you want to Continue?(y/n)");
            Choice2 = Console.ReadLine();
        } while (Choice2 == "y");
        Console.WriteLine("GOODBYE");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }


    public static void Output(int Choices, List<Employee> employList)
    {
        switch (Choices)
        {
            case 1:
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("List of PLayers Participated in Football");
                Console.WriteLine("========================================");
                Employee.DataBaseSearch(employList, Choices);
                break;
            case 2:
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("List of PLayers Participated in Cricket");
                Console.WriteLine("=======================================");
                Employee.DataBaseSearch(employList, Choices);
                break;
            case 3:
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("List of PLayers Participated in Chess");
                Console.WriteLine("=====================================");
                Employee.DataBaseSearch(employList, Choices);
                break;
            case 4:
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Entire DataBase");
                Console.WriteLine("===============");
                Employee.DataBaseDisplay(employList);
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input");
                break;
        }
    }
}

//public enum G 
//{
//    Football = 1,
//    Cicket = 2,
//    Chess = 3
//}

class MenuDisplay
{
    public static void DisplayEvents()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Menu");
        Console.WriteLine("==========");
        Console.WriteLine("1.FootBall");
        Console.WriteLine("2.Cricket");
        Console.WriteLine("3.Chess");
        Console.WriteLine("4.Display DataBase");
    }
}

class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int EventID { get; set; }

    public static void DataBaseSearch(List<Employee> employeeList, int Choices)
    {
        foreach (Employee employee in employeeList)
        {
            if (employee.EventID == Choices)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(employee.ID + " - " + employee.Name);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void DataBaseDisplay(List<Employee> employeeList)
    {
        foreach (Employee employee in employeeList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(employee.ID + " - " + employee.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Thank you

Comment: And what exactly doesn't work on this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've designed it, an employee can't participate in multiple events. That's because your `Employee` class stores an association to an event with this line:

```
public int EventID { get; set; }
```

That means an employee has exactly one event. What you want is for an employee to be able to be associated with a collection of events. So you want something like:

```
public IEnumerable<int> EventIDs { get; set; }
```

You will need to make a corresponding update to your `DataBaseSearch` method

```
public static void DataBaseSearch(List<Employee> employeeList, int Choices)
{
    foreach (Employee employee in employeeList)
    {
        if (employee.EventIDs.Contains(Choices))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(employee.ID + " - " + employee.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

And you'll need to update the lines where you add employees at the beginning of the program too, something like:

```
empList.Add(new Employee() { ID = 101, Name = "Parvez Ali", EventID = new List<int> { 1, 2 } });
```

Comment: employee.EventIDs.Contains(Choices) is giving error do i need to add some thing more??

Comment: Sir you have helped me a lot but the program is giving error for .Contains .. can you help me to fix this error

Comment: @user3508595 Add `using System.Linq;` right at the top of the class.

Comment: Thank you Sir very very much.it has been solved. Can i get any of you Email Id or Skype Id or Facebook Id, where i can Personally Get in touch with you for Help on C#.Please Sir.

Comment: @user3508595 Sorry, no.